# LINQ Group By and merge properties and Summarize the Invoice Number

Tags: c#, linq

I have the follow List(**InputData**), and I would like to group by **Vendor**  then by **Type** and Summarize by **NumberInvoice** and Concatenate by **Month** [as you see the Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdiiv.png)
and this is [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEaBa.png)

```
private static void Main()
    {
        var InputData= new List<Invoice>()
        {
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "PC", Month = 1 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "PC", Month = 2 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "Surface", Month = 1 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 20, Type= "PC", Month = 1 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 20, Type= "PC", Month = 2 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 30, Type= "Surface", Month = 1 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "IBM", NumberInvoice= 50, Type= "Network", Month = 5 },
        new Invoice{ Vendor = "IBM", NumberInvoice= 60, Type= "Graphic Card", Month = 6 }
        };
    }
    
    public class Invoice
    {
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
        public int NumberInvoice{ get; set; }
        public string Type{ get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
    }
```

I did this so far, but it is not working as my output result.
If I comment the follow line, it will show my result but without Summarizing.

```
//NumberInvoice = Enumerable.Sum((decimal)key.NumberInvoice)
```

The Code:

```
var result = InputData
                    .GroupBy(
                        x => new {
                            x.Vendor,
                            x.Type,
                            x.NumberInvoice
                        }, // key selector
                        x => x.Month, // element selector
                        (key, month) => new Invoice
                        {
                            Vendor = key.Vendor,
                            Type = key.Type,
                            month = string.Join(",", month),
                            NumberInvoice = Enumerable.Sum((decimal)key.NumberInvoice)
                        })
                    .ToList();
```

**Update (Explain):**
I need to Group by Columns, and concatenate 1 column, and do the Sum for 1 Column.

1. Group by : 1st by **Vendor** then by **Type**
2. Concatenate by: **Month**
3. Sum by :**NumberInvoice**

So the result in above example is:
[This the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo97U.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output, because your prose description is a little unclear to me.

Comment: an imlage already attached

Comment: Which you have confusing called "input data" not "desired output"...

Comment: It seems like you want to group by Vendor, Invoice Number, and Type. No summing is needed to produce that result, so I'm not sure why you're trying to sum anything.

Comment: of course I need to sum the amount after grouping, or should not?

Comment: You don't show anything summed in your screenshot. "Number Invoice" is exactly the same as it is in your source data. All you need to do is collect your months, which it seems you have already done.

Comment: If you were to sum your "Number Invoice", then Microsoft/10//PC occurs twice, so I would expect your output to be Microsoft/20/PC/1,2 if you were summing invoice number (10 + 10 = 20), but clearly that is not the case, and it doesn't really seem to make sense to.

Comment: So summing is adding two or more numbers together, right? Like 1+1 = 2, or 1+2+4 = 7. Where is the summing in your data?

Comment: Your result can not be of type Invoice if month is defined as a int rather than a string. Other than that you just need to change your last line to be `NumberInvoice =  key.NumberInvoice,`

Comment: NumberInvoice =  key.NumberInvoice ==> will not summerize it

Comment: What do you mean by summerize? That's not a word that can apply here. Look it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Sum of  NumberInvoice, after Grouping.

Comment: So should your first result in your output image actually say 20 instead of 10? It seems you perhaps want `NumberInvoice = key.NumberInvoice * month.Count();` in that case.

Comment: I updated my question, plz check it, and check the new attached screenshot, thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
            var result = InputData
                .OrderBy(x => x.Month)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                .SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => new {y.Vendor, y.Type, y.NumberInvoice})
                .Select(y => new { Vendor = y.Key.Vendor, Type = y.Key.Type, month = x.Key, numberInvoices = y.Count()}).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result  = InputData
    // Group by Vendor and Type
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Vendor, x.Type, })
    .Select(g => new  //  Invoice
    {
        Vendor = g.Key.Vendor,
        Type = g.Key.Type,

        // Select all the distinct months in the group and concatenate them
        Month = String.Join(",", g.Select(a => a.Month).OrderBy(a => a).Distinct()),

        // Sum all the NumberInvoices in the group
        NumberInvoice = g.Sum(a => a.NumberInvoice),
    });
```

Outputs

[image]